# Scaling a Cursor in Java

Tags: java, cursor, mouse, scaling

I want to scale the cursor but the Cursor class in Java API does not have any method to scale a cursor. I need to scale the cursor, please suggest some method or code in Java to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom cursor with Toolkit's

```
createCustomCursor(Image cursor, Point hotSpot, String name)
```

method. This could be a larger image.

Comment: but it only gives size of 32x32. How can i increase the size of cursor greater than 32x32 pixels.

Comment: @Programmer By setting the `Image cursor` argument to be an image larger than 32x32